# Geonetwork 4.0 - Login problems

Tags: geonetwork

Today I updated my geonetwork to version 4.0, but now I can't login.
I get error 403 - Forbidden.

I'm using tomcat9 and Apache2.

Configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName teste@teste.com

 SSLCertificateFile fullchain.pem
 SSLCertificateKeyFile privkey.pem
 Include options-ssl-apache.conf

 ProxyRequests Off

 <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
 </Proxy>

 ProxyPass /geonetwork http://localhost:8080/geonetwork
 ProxyPassReverse /geonetwork http://localhost:8080/geonetwork

 ProxyPreserveHost On
```